# Google Map is not showing on live site using Avada theme

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps

Hello I am working with Wordpress and  using Avada theme. I used  Google Map Which

is built in functionality of Avada theme it is working fine on Localhost.Google

Map is not showing on the live site.

Here is [site Url](http://qingdomjuice.com/dev/)

When I get source code of this page from live site and run Google map is

showing. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 5):

In localhost no need to use api that's why working on your local environment. But in live site you need to add google api keys so it will working.

Google Maps API error = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY”

and than check on live environment.

Answer (score 0):

Tested for Avada 3.8.8 Google Maps Error Solved

Google Map Requires an API key now to work properly on the Website.

Using avada theme 4.0 Higher you will get the API key field in theme options > contact > Google Map Section .

But if you are using avada theme lesser than 4.0 than you will have place script in the themes > avada > contact.php

Place the following above the start of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY_HERE"></script>
```

I know it is not the efficient solution for wordpress but saves lot of time and also frustration , lot of people might be using avada 3.x version .

Also Don't Forgot to enable the API from Google API Console.